# Handling arguments in order for preprocessing in Python, when order matters

Tags: python, function, arguments

I would like to make a difference with named variables regarding the order of appearance.

I want to have a pipeline on editing images for which it makes a difference which techniques I apply first. Rather than call the functions separately, I would still like to make use of a wrapper function.

E.g.:

```
def preprocess(cutoff=None, resize=None, blur=None):
    ....
```

Now if I call the function like `preprocess(resize=(100, 100), cutoff=55)`, I'd like it to first `resize`, and then do the cut off, though vice-versa when `preprocess(cutoff=55, resize=(100,100))`.

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Why do you want this to be a single function? It seems like a counter-intuitive design, and if we knew the reasoning behind it, I'll bet someone could come up with a better design that solved the same problems.

Comment: The main reason is that I know there will be mostly default behavior, but I'm now finding out that perhaps at some occasions I'd like to switch the order again. This way it will still be possible to briefly call it like `preprocess(5, (10,10))`, but still the cycle is not fully deterministic and many long function names are now not needed.

Comment: What about having a `resize` method, a `cutoff` method, a `blur` method, and then a `preprocess` method that's just there for the (very common) case when you want 1 to 3 of those in the most common order? So, normally you just call `preprocess(5, (10,10))`, but if you want to do things backward, you do `resize(10, 10).cutoff(5)`?

Comment: I guess that's fair enough. Thanks for sharing your ideas. I was thinking perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Well, it probably isn't _obvious_ that the feature you're looking for doesn't exist. In fact, if `OrderedDict`'s current clever optimized implementation had been invented before `**kwargs` syntax, it may have been doable (not very common, but not banned, because why bother banning it?) just by iterating `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use keyword arguments for that. If you accept them via normal parameters like you've tried, the only order is the order of the parameters. If you accept them via `**kwargs`, you get a `dict` (which has no order).

If you want to know the order of the arguments, they have to be positional arguments; there's really no way around that.

However, there might be a better design for this. For example, why not just make them separate methods? Then, instead of this:

```
newfoo = foo.preprocess(resize=(100, 100), cutoff=55)
```

… you do this:

```
newfoo = foo.resize(100, 100).cutoff(55)
```

---

Or provide simple types that do nothing but wrap up the arguments:

```
newfoo = foo.preprocess(Resize(100, 100), Cutoff(55))
```

Then you can have `preprocess` take its arguments by `*args` and dispatch based on `type(arg)`.

---

And if you look at how you'd implement that, it points to another possibility:

```
class DumbArgWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

class Resize(DumbArgWrapper): pass
class Cutoff(DumbArgWrapper): pass
class Blur(DumbArgWrapper): pass

class ImageProcessor(object):
    def preprocess(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, Resize):
                do_resize(*arg.args)
            # etc.
```

If you just move the `do_resize` code into `Resize` (in other words, make it a sort of "lazy function" object), it's much cleaner:

```
class SmartArgWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

class Resize(SmartArgWrapper):
    def __call__(self, target):
        do_resize(target, *self.args)
# etc.

class ImageProcessor(object):
    def preprocess(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            arg(self)
```

---

And having done that, you could just make a simple wrapper that turns any function into a `SmartArtWrapper`, instead of making a bunch of subclasses.

And then…

---

The point is, there are plenty of possibilities. To someone who knows what you want and why, there should be one and only one obvious way to do it… but to someone who has no idea what you want and why, that isn't true.

Comment: "There are plenty of other possibilities". For example one thing that's fairly popular with third-party library designers in all programming languages that support operator overloading, is to chain together sequential operations using the `|` operator. So in this case do without the `preprocess` function and write `foo | resize(100,100) | cutoff(55)`. This can lead to some muddy interfaces, though, which I suspect is why the first-party language designers reach for it less readily ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: I wouldn't say it's popular in "all programming languages that support operator overloading"—in particular, it's not popular or idiomatic in Python. (In C++, on the other hand…)

Comment: "Popular" may be the wrong word. I just mean that someone always tries to do it, not that people do so routinely. Last I looked I found a couple of attempts for Python, and I didn't look hard. It's not like every library-writer in C++ reaches straight for `|` as a pipeline operator either, most still use function calls. But sure it's much more common in C++ than in Python.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Sure, as long as you can do it, someone will… Just like writing a C++-boost-lambda-style [quicklambda](https://github.com/abarnert/quicklambda) for fun; only an idiot would actually do that in Python, and yet, I did it. :)